# How to use testng tag for smoke, regression tests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, page-factory

I have several test methods and i need to select some of them as smoke tests and others regression tests. How can i make a condition/dependency in Testng selenium, So smoke tests will run first as a group. And i can set up different Bamboo job for regression tests and those will be running only if smoke test group passed.

Here's my tests are:

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void test_1(){
----}

@Test(priority=2)
public void test_2(){
----}

@Test(priority=3)
public void test_3(){
----}

@Test(priority=4)
public void test_4(){
----}

@Test(priority=5)
public void test_5(){
----}
```

Here, test_1 to test_3 are smoke tests. So if they pass others will be executed. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the [groups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) and [dependsOnGroups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) annotations. The examples in the documentation are pretty good. Basically you could try something like this:

```
@Test (groups = {"smokeTest"}, priority=1)
public void test_1() {...}

// add the same annotations for test_2 and test_3

@Test (groups = {"regressionTest"}, dependsOnGroups = {"smokeTest"}, priority=4) 
public void test_4() {...}

@Test (groups = {"regressionTest"}, dependsOnGroups = {"smokeTest"}, priority=5) 
public void test_5() {...}
```

This way tests 4 and 5 will only be executed if tests 1,2 and 3 pass. If you need more granular control, you could consider using [testng.xml](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) to set up test suites etc.

As for setting up the jobs in Bamboo, it depends on the build tool you are using. This [post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/How-to-configure-and-run-Selenium-TestNG-in-Bamboo-I-need-a/qaq-p/46454) on Atlassian community may be helpful for you.

Hope this helps.