# Selenium Eclipse Test Suite tests fail in the suite, but are successful when run individually

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing

I have the following test suite to run an automation script to login to gmail then another script to click the Compose button:

**TestSuite.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Web Admin Tests" parallel="false">
<test name="BOS - Account Class">
<classes>
<class name="secondtestngpackage.GmailComposeEmail" />
<class name="secondtestngpackage.GmailLogin" />
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

When I run this test suite, the first test does not get passed the login screen in gmail, but the second test does, even though they reference the same functions.  Is there a reason why this would happen?  One test is able to enter the user id and password, since it is the second/last test, but when the first test is run, it is like the second test interferes with it, since its browser is now in focus.

**GmailLogin.java:**

```
 @BeforeTest
  public void launchBrowser() {
      ReuseFunctions.OpenApp("Chrome", "https://gmail.com");
  }

//Test 1:  Log into Gmail
  @Test(priority=1)
  public void LoginToGmailAccount() {

**GmailComposeEmail.java**

  @BeforeTest
  public void launchBrowser() {
      ReuseFunctions.OpenApp("Chrome", "https://gmail.com");

  }
  @Test(priority=2)
  public void LoginToGmailAccount() {
```

**Reusable Functions File:**

```
ReuseFunctions.func_EnterCredentials("username", "password");

        public class ReuseFunctions {

    public static WebDriver driver; 

/*Function 1:  Select Browser and Open Application Function
*/
    public static Object OpenApp (String Browser, String URL) {
        //Receive Browser Name Function
        Func_LaunchBrowser(Browser);
        //Receive Website and Open Function
        func_OpenURL(URL);
        return driver;
    }

    //Select Browser
    public static WebDriver Func_LaunchBrowser(String Browser) {
        String driverPath = "C:/EclipseJavaDev/";
        if(Browser=="Chrome"){
            System.out.println("launching chrome browser"); 
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }else if(Browser=="FF"){
            driver= new FirefoxDriver();
            }else if(Browser=="IE"){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return driver;
            }
    //Open URL
    public static void func_OpenURL(String URL){
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with where your `WebDriver` instance is instantiated. Think of each instance of `WebDriver` as a unique browser session. So the safest way to ensure each test gets its own driver instance (browser session), is to initialize it at the Test class, not the common helper class.

GmailLogin:

```
// Initialize Webdriver and then asks your common function to return it
private WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void launchBrowser() {
  driver = ReuseFunctions.OpenApp("Chrome", "https://gmail.com");
}

@Test(priority=1)
public void LoginToGmailAccount() {
   // pass driver as a method argument to other methods
}

//Don't forget to close the browser
@AfterTest
public void quitBrowser() {
  driver.quit();
}
```

Refactor your other Test class the same away as above. (Or reconsider if you really need another class. You could just add another method into the same class and use `priority` and/or `dependsOnMethods` [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654996/how-to-use-testng-tag-for-smoke-regression-tests/45656431#45656431) to control the execution order. But that is a different topic and out of the scope of this question :) ).

ReuseFunctions:

```
// Remove the global Webdriver instantiation

//Change return type from Object to WebDriver
public static WebDriver OpenApp (String Browser, String URL) {
    WebDriver driver = Func_LaunchBrowser(Browser);
    func_OpenURL(URL, driver); //pass in the driver as arg
    return driver;
}

//Refactor openUrl method to use the driver from arg
public static void func_OpenURL(String URL, WebDriver driver){...}
```

This should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I will attempt this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked great.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Great! Could you do me a favor and accept my answer please. @Ma St