# How to run high priority tests in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng, ui-automation

How can we run only high priority test scripts in selenium.

Example : I have 5 tests as 
login, place order, change order, raise ticket, logout.

Now my priority testcases to be run are login, place order, raise ticket.

Is there any way without using include/exclude tags in testNG?

Comment: Selenium won't be able to prioritize your testcases but TestNG would be. Consider removing the Selenium tag.

Comment: May I know how it can be done in testNG

Answer (score 1):

Use the `priority` argument of `@Test` Annotation.
Lower priorities will be scheduled first.
See - https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: Hi Shatulsky , if I use priority, tests are executing the the high priority to low priority order.. but my expectation is not to run low priority test cases but only high priority testcases.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654996/how-to-use-testng-tag-for-smoke-regression-tests

Answer (score 0):

You can use priority to mention the execution **order** so as per the given priority, @Test methods will be executed . For this you need TestNG library as a dependency. If you wish 
to run particular set of tests only you can use TestNG's grouping feature . Please see https://www.guru99.com/introduction-testng-groups.html

```
public class TestngPriority {
    @Test(priority = 1)

    public void Test1() {

        System.out.println("1");

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)

    public void Test2() {

        System.out.println("2");


    }

    @Test(priority = 3)

    public void Test3() {

        System.out.println("3");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although make `Groups` of test cases is recommended solution for your case but it can not be achieved without `include` and `exclude` tag. Still there is one solution.

**Solution:** make 2 testng. xml file for high and low priority test cases.

High Priority can have login, place order and raise ticket

```
    <suite name="HighPriority">
         <test name="Test1">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.multiplesuite.smoke.smokeClassOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
    </suite>
```

and Low priority can have  change order & logout.

```
    <suite name="LowPriority">
                <test name="Test2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.multiplesuite.smoke.smokeClassTwo"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
    </suite>
```

Now define a Master testng.xml file to call both

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="MultipleSuite">
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="HighPriority.xml"></suite-file>
    <suite-file path="LowPriority.xml"></suite-file>
</suite-files>
</suite>
```

This way you can run individual test suite OR both test suite together.

With Maven you can run any xml file by Name as given below. It will work on Jenkins too.

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=HighPriority.xml
```

Hope it will help you.