# How can I use TestNG's @Tag annotation? I am unable to find any documentation anywhere. (Smoke Testing)

Tags: java, gradle, junit, testng

I am really new to all this stuff. I have to identify a subset of tests from our testing suite to create some smoke tests.

I was able to find some documentation on how to use the `@Tag` annotation for JUnit 5, and I saw that there is also a `@Tag` annotation for TestNG 6.x.x, but I am literally unable to find any examples online or any documentation saying how to use it.

I am aware of the Grouping feature on JUnit and TestNG -- is this typically the way that smoke testing is done? By grouping tests?

I spoke with the sr engineer on my team and he told me to look into the `@Tag` to use it as a filtering mechanism for smoke testing so I am kind of stuck on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654996/how-to-use-testng-tag-for-smoke-regression-tests) (it's worth checking out as well), I wanted to answer it to provide more sources showing that the "tagging" mechanism is in fact implemented as "test groups" in TestNG. `@Tag` annotation is a JUnit annotation and serves a similar purpose. You can read the articles below to see it in code:

- https://blog.frankel.ch/reassessing-testng-junit/#grouping
- https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/junit-5-vs-testng/#crayon-62f9dd2e9f955062559746
- https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/junit-vs-testng/amp/#6_Group_Tests

[TestNG documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) describes the grouping mechanism as well. I suppose that the senior engineer you've asked thought about a mechanism of tagging/grouping, which is conceptually the same thing, but is just named different in different testing tools.

To sum up: JUnit `@Tag` annotation is the same mechanism as TestNG `groups` attribute of `@Test` annotation.

Comment: Thanks Jonasz. That makes sense. However, in TestNG v6, there is an import for the @Tag annotation `import org.testng.xml.dom.Tag`. I tried searching every where for some code snippets or documentation on how to use it, but I could not. Afaik it is discontinued in v7, but now I know it's under the `groups` feature.

Comment: The package name implies that it's something XML-related, probably an interface that marks a class, which should be parsed based on an XML tag, maybe from a testing.xml configuration file.